# Lebesgue differentiation theorem with two variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral

We know that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous then 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h} f(s)ds=f(x).$$
But if we have $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, what kind of dependence in the second variable we should assume to have:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h} f(s,h)ds=f(x,0)\ \ \ \ ?$$

Comment: The second equation doesn't quite make sense. You have $f(x)$ on the right-hand side while $f$ is a function of two variables.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit that.